# Getting exception when requesting XSRF-TOKEN using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, csrf, resttemplate

I'm trying to call a service which has CSRF enabled and all it's endpoints are configured to request authentication header from the user.

I'm using Spring RestTemplate as follows:

```
 ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = getRestTemplate().exchange(
      "localhost:9090/",
       "HEAD",
       entity,
       String.class);
return responseEntity.getBody();
```

However, I'm not able to read the Headers from the response as I'm getting `HTTP 401` error.

My workaround is to read the token from the exception that RestTemplate throws `HttpClientErrorException`. Like this:

```
exception.getResponseHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
for (String header : headers) {
   if (header.startsWith("XSRF-TOKEN")) {
        token = header.split("=")[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get XSRF-TOKEN token with out relying on reading it from the exception?

Comment: Is it possible to make experimental project reproducing the issue and share via git? it would be more clear how to help you resolve 401 code

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting an exception when accessing with GET method. Hence, I would create a get endpoint for retrieving the token and then use it for next POST calls.

Hope that approach makes sense.

Comment: Is this a secure and common approach? Do you have some sources I can read regarding this?

Comment: @alayor Well, If there is not any http session / browser involved in that restful service I wouldn't use a CSRF protection. Have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html , there is a clear example of a CSRF attack. You can evaluate that risk to your service.

Comment: In this case there is a browser involved. This is a test project that acts as if it were a browser in order to validate responses from the server.

Answer (score 1):

the csrf only blocks requests of type post, put, delete ... that is, the get is free, therefore in order to obtain the token, first you have to make a request to a get method and extract the token from there that you would use to the next requests.
in case the token is not generated, add this to the configure of your security configuration:

```
http.csrf (). csrfTokenRepository (CookieCrsfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse) .any () ........
```

Answer (score 0):

`XSRF-TOKEN` following spring specification is marker for header by default. So you should try get it in this way:

```
List tokenList = responseEntity.getHeaders().get("XSRF-TOKEN");
```

This collection consist of single element as usual, so first element should be your token.

Comment: The problem is that `responseEntity` is null. This is because I get an exception in `exchange`

Comment: but you used `responseEntity.getBody()` isn't it?

Comment: The execution doesn't reach that line.